# How to grab data from webpage in C#/XAML

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am brand new when it comes to Windows Phone 7 development.  I've downloaded Windows Phone SDK 7.1 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.  For practice, I'm trying to make an app that will visit weather.com and pull the current local weather.

I know how to visit a website using the WebBrowser tool in the ToolBox but that's not quite what I want to do.  I want it pull the weather when I launch the app.  What would the XAML and/or C# code look like that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library to parse html. Or you can use `WebClient` to download the data and parse it yourself. Also, check if you have any API for the weather network, that'll be much more easier and better for your app.

Comment: There is an [API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/?ref=twc), but it's only free for the first 500 calls/day.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest use htmlagilitypack, you can use xpath or xml among other things to get the values you're looking for. Just be aware that if they change css or ids or controls you'll have to update your app to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Forget Apis and webbrowser. Use httprequest,
Httpresponse, u have way more flexibility

system.web

Comment: +1 HttpWebRequest, HttpWebResponse give more flexibility or using RestSharp which wraps those and also provides XML/Json parsing and lets you using any parser as well.  Chances are you won't need an HTML parser for data you get back from an API call.